# How to whitelist access on certain files to certain subdomains in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a subdomain that uses file_get_contents in php, and I need that to access an otherwise restricted file. In my .htaccess I have

```
<Files "file.txt">  
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from subdomain.site.com
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

The main problem I have here is that it doesn't unblock access from `subdomain.site.com`. I can't access the subdomain via url path because of site isolation set in place by my hosting provider.

The tutorial I have found says that you can whitelist certain websites to access this file. But, for some reason even following their syntax, it for some reason won't whitelist that site.

Tutorial:

- https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/#developing_sites

Comment: Don't use `http://` in getting file contents, just get it directly using file system path

Comment: @anubhava I tried, but I can't access the file. I don't know why either, since I don't have access to the site's shell, meaning I can't catch the warning it throws

Comment: 1. please check the path to the file especially from the perspective of the process trying to access the file and 2. find out how you can access the contents of the http server's error log file. _You cannot operate a site without access to that information._ If you do not have direct access, then contact your service provider and ask how to access that information. If they cannot provide that information then change the service provider.

Comment: @arkascha I don't have access to that information, I know, they explicitly told me.  And I tried accessing the folder, and it gave me a 404, so either I'm not doing it right, or it's blocked in some sort of way. Either way, I just want to know how to unblock a url for a file. Is that possible? I just want to know this for now, and future projects. I just want to know _is there a way to allow access via url_?

Comment: How should such a question be answered without knowing the cause of the issue? That is why you need access to the log information.

Comment: @arkascha ok, but  I don't need error info to know how to whitelist  urls. I will check into that later, I know the importance of getting error info, but I just need help right now on whitelisting urls via .htaccess.

Comment: You did whitelist access to a file with the rule you posted. The issue: there is not a single magic rule to achieve that, but thousands of situations with thousands of rules. Fact is> the rule you implemented does not work. So the question you have to answer is: WHY doesn't it work as expected. If you know the cause you can fix it. That is a general rule: you cannot fix something without knowing what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I was afraid of that, oh well. Can you make an answer relating to your comments so I can mark it as the answer? I really did find your information useful @arkascha

Comment: I did not answer your question, which is why I did not post an answer. Fine if I could help, but that is all I can offer. Good look sorting out your issue. And once more: a web service provider unable to provide you logging information? That is a disqualification in my eyes...

Comment: @arkascha It's a free hosting web platform. This is more of a learning experience for me, so I don't want to waste money if I don't have to :/ Anyways, thanks. If I am going to make an actual professional website, I'll be sure to use one with shell access and plenty of tools of the sort.

Comment: Think of it this way: you currently save maybe 1,99 Euros a month. Great. For that you miss the chance to understand and learn and get forward. Sure it is wise to insist in something free?

Comment: I guess, thanks anyways. I'll find a way to fix it somehow, I'm going to use file_get_contents, since It's a subdomain if I can. Like I said, thanks for the advice though